# content control in Microsoft Word 7

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, visual-basic

What I require seems simple to me but I'm really struggling to sort it.

I need a drop down box (combo box) that has a list containing two values. I want the first value to be displayed so the user can select it. I want the corresponding value to be displayed in a text box on another line.

eg.

data: tom - 19a, peter - 31c, fred - 32 15d

I want to select : tom, peter, fred. from a list and have the value (19a, 31c, 32 15d) that matches it in a text box on a separate line

The data table is static and wont change. i just need to select the relevant values for printing